# Making calculations using counter

Tags: counters, loops

I need to use the counter to make some computations inside loops. For instance,
I want to write a for loop to get the following:

[image]

[image]

What is the best way to write using `\forloop`? Using `\forloop` and `\newcounter`, I am unable to perform operations on the counter, i.e., I am unable to perform operations like `2*k-1`, where `k` is the counter in the `\forloop`.

Comment: LaTeX's counters are not really for computations (one has to prefix with `\c@` the counter name to get the underlying TeX count register). Try `\newcount\cnti` (once), and `\the\numexpr 2*\cnti-1\relax` in your constructions (`\advance\cnti\@ne`)

Comment: @jfbu Could you expand your comment to an answer with an example? Thanks.

Comment: Do you just want to display the equations above or are you interested in actually evaluating `A_{11}` times `x_1` plus `A_{12}` times `x_2`? We don't know what the matrices `A` and `x` hold, if you're after the latter.

Comment: Well, sure, but I need to have a bit more of context, perhaps you need a so-called `expandable` loop. Do you just want some code to produce the lines as shown in your image? are you going to need it also for, say 77, rather than 10? I will post a tentative answer, which may not fit the bill. I am confident some answers by others will show up quickly also.

Comment: @Werner I am not interested in evaluating the matrix-vector product, I am just interested in displaying them in the symbolic form.

Comment: @jfbu: It's not necessary to go into the internals of the counter structure: `\value{<counter>}` gives the raw count register.

Comment: @RyanReich: yes, the way I formulated things in that earlier comment is rather poor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

A combination of `forloop` and `calc`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{forloop}
\begin{document}

\hsize=8cm
\newcounter{k}\newcounter{j}%
\begin{align}
%forloop[ step ]{ counter }{ initial value }{ condition }{ code }
\nonumber
\forloop{k}{1}{\value{k} < 11}{
\setcounter{j}{2*\value{k}-1}
\\ y_{\arabic{k}}&=A_{\arabic{k},\arabic{j}} x_{\arabic{j}}
\addtocounter{j}{1}
+A_{\arabic{k},\arabic{j}} x_{\arabic{j}}
}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. and thanks. I was looking for something along these lines.

Answer (score 11):

Here another approach using l3int:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse} %dt. Silbentrennung
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_set:Nn { Nx }
\NewDocumentCommand \Formula { O{1} O{1} m }
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnnn
     { #1 }%initial value
     { #2 }%step
     { #3 - #2 }%final value
     { \formula_func_aux:n { ##1 } \\ }%code
  \formula_func_aux:n { #3 } %last line without \\
 }

\cs_new:Npn  \formula_func_aux:n #1
 {
  \int_gset:Nn \g_tmpa_int { #1 }
      y \sb{ \int_use:N \g_tmpa_int } &=
      \int_gset:Nn \g_tmpb_int { 2 * \g_tmpa_int -1  }
      A \sb{ \int_use:N \g_tmpa_int , \int_use:N \g_tmpb_int }
      x \sb{ \int_use:N \g_tmpb_int }
     +
      \int_gset:Nn \g_tmpb_int { 2 * \g_tmpa_int }
      A \sb{ \int_use:N \g_tmpa_int , \int_use:N \g_tmpb_int }
      x \sb{ \int_use:N \g_tmpb_int } 
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\Formula{2}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\Formula[1][2]{6}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

[image]

This also uses no counters but is perhaps a bit simpler than jfbu's but is the same idea.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\newcommand\y[1]{%
y_{\the#1}&=A_{\the#1\,\the\numexpr2*#1-1\relax}
      +A_{\the#1\,\the\numexpr2*#1\relax}
        x_{\the\numexpr2*#1\relax}}

\def\lp#1#2#3{\ifnum#1=#3\relax\stoplp\fi#2{\numexpr#1\relax}\\\lp{\numexpr#1+1\relax}#2{#3}}

\def\stoplp#1\\#2#3#4#5{#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\lp1\y{10}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: yes, simpler indeed! my answer builds expandably the complete thing and only at the end re-inserts it in the token stream... (professional deformation due to work on a package).

Answer (score 8):

Here's a way to do it, by using a regular `array` for alignment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multido
\begin{document}
\def\yeqns{}
\[\begin{array}{r@{}l}
  \begingroup
  \let\\\relax
  \multido{\iKa=1+1,\iKb=2+2,\iKc=1+2}{10}{%
    \xdef\yeqns{\yeqns% Gather equations for y
      y_{\iKa} &{}= A_{\iKa,\iKc}x_{\iKc}+A_{\iKa,\iKb}x_{\iKb} \\}}
  \endgroup
  \yeqns% Print equations
\end{array}\]
\end{document}
```

Technically, there's no calculations performed on the counters and I've separated row/column indices using `,` (you can change that).

[`multido`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multido) helps set up the iterative evaluation of items I called `\iKa`, `\iKb` and `\iKc` (respectively defined as k, 2k and 2k-1).

Answer (score 7):

A fairly general method, with a "simple macro" and a complex one that's completely customizable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,amsmath}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% #1 = number of x's
% #2 = number of equations
\NewDocumentCommand{\makeequations}{O{2}m}
 {
  \egreg_makeequations:nnnnnn { x } { y } { A } { 1 } { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_egreg_equations_tl
\seq_new:N \l_egreg_equation_seq

% #1 = variables on RHS
% #2 = variable on LHS
% #3 = coefficient letter
% #4 = starting point
% #5 = number of variables in RHS
% #6 = number of equations
\cs_new_protected:Npn \egreg_makeequations:nnnnnn #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_egreg_equations_tl
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { #4 } { 1 } { #4+#6-1 }
   {
    \egreg_makeequation:nnnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #5 } { ##1 }
    \int_compare:nF { ##1 = #4+#6-1 }
     { \tl_put_right:Nn \l_egreg_equations_tl { \\ } }
   }
  \use:x
   {
    \exp_not:n { \begin{align} }
    \exp_not:V { \l_egreg_equations_tl }
    \exp_not:n { \end{align} }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \egreg_makeequation:nnnnn #1 #2 #3 #4 #5
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_egreg_equations_tl { #2\sb{#5} & = }
  \seq_clear:N \l_egreg_equation_seq
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { #4 * (#5-1) + 1 } { 1 } { #4 * #5 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_egreg_equation_seq
     { 
      #3\sb{#5 \egreg_comma:nn { #5 } { ##1 } ##1}#1\sb{##1}
     }
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l_egreg_equations_tl 
   { \seq_use:Nnnn \l_egreg_equation_seq {+}{+}{+} }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \egreg_comma:nn #1 #2
 {
  \bool_if:nT 
   { \int_compare_p:n {#1 > 9} || \int_compare_p:n { #2 > 9 } }
   { , }
 }

\keys_define:nn { makeequations }
 {
  LHSvar .tl_set:N  = \l_egreg_eqs_lhsvar_tl, LHSvar .initial:n = y,
  RHSvar .tl_set:N  = \l_egreg_eqs_rhsvar_tl, RHSvar .initial:n = x,
  COEFF  .tl_set:N  = \l_egreg_eqs_coeff_tl,  COEFF  .initial:n = A,
  EQS    .int_set:N = \l_egreg_eqs_eqs_int,   
  VARS   .int_set:N = \l_egreg_eqs_vars_int,  VARS   .initial:n = 2,
  START  .int_set:N = \l_egreg_eqs_start_int, START  .initial:n = 1,
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\xmakeequations}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { makeequations } { #1 }
  \egreg_makeequations:VVVVVV
   \l_egreg_eqs_rhsvar_tl
   \l_egreg_eqs_lhsvar_tl
   \l_egreg_eqs_coeff_tl
   \l_egreg_eqs_start_int
   \l_egreg_eqs_vars_int
   \l_egreg_eqs_eqs_int
  \group_end:
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \egreg_makeequations:nnnnnn { VVVVVV }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\makeequations{3}

\makeequations[3]{4}

\xmakeequations{EQS=3}

\xmakeequations{EQS=4,VARS=3,COEFF=R,LHSvar=p,RHSvar=q,START=100}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the simple macro you simply state the number of equations and, optionally, the number of variables used in the right hand side.

In the complex macro, with a key-value syntax, you can also change the letters used for the variables and the coefficients, but also the starting point. So, for instance, you can chain calls with

```
\xmakeequations{EQS=3}
Some text in between
\xmakeequations{EQS=4,START=4}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You see? three answers already, almost immediately. Mine is comparatively tremendously complicated. I started in a certain direction, and wanted to get it done that way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\CreateEquations[2]{%
   \expandafter\@createequations@a\expandafter
   {\the\numexpr #1\expandafter }\expandafter{\the\numexpr #2}%
}%

\def\@createequations@a #1#2%
{%
    \ifnum #1>#2 
          \expandafter\@gobblefour
    \else 
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
          \@createequations@b
    \fi
    \expandafter {\@createoneequation{#1}}{#1}{#2}%
}%

\def\@createequations@b #1#2#3%
{%
    \ifnum #2<#3
        \expandafter\@createequations@c\expandafter
        {\the\numexpr #2+1\expandafter}%
    \fi \@createequations@finish {#1}{#3}%
}%

\def\@createequations@c #1\@createequations@finish
{%
    \expandafter\@createequations@d\expandafter
     {\@createoneequation {#1}}{#1}%
}%

\def\@createequations@d #1#2#3{\@createequations@b {#3\\ #1}{#2}}%

\def\@createequations@finish #1#2{\begin{align}
                                    #1
                                  \end{align}}

\def\@createoneequation #1{%
     y_{#1} &=A_{#1,\the\numexpr 2*#1-1\relax}
                         x_{\the\numexpr 2*#1-1\relax}
                        +A_{#1,\the\numexpr 2*#1\relax}
                         x_{\the\numexpr 2*#1\relax}%
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

  \CreateEquations {1}{10}

  \CreateEquations {1}{-1}

  \CreateEquations {100}{103}


\end{document}
```

[image: equations]

Comment: and I forgot to say that this code uses no counters at all...

Comment: +++1 I was half way through an answer along these lines, but then it was meal time.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have to lose weight, this gives me a distinctive advantage... just had a light soup...

Comment: I decided to finsh mine off and post mine as well, but still +1 to you:-)

Answer (score 4):

*(edit) 2017: since `xint 1.1 (2014/10/28)` one needs here `\usepackage{xinttools}`. Code updated to replace the `\usepackage{xint}` of initial answer.*

I propose one more answer, which uses expandable macros from the [xint package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xint), version `1.06a` or later. Here, the case of an empty set of indices is treated less well than in my other answer (an empty align environment is typeset, which makes an increase in the equation counter), this could be fixed of course. Also, contrarily to my other answer, here the indices must be explicit integers not count registers. This also could be fixed, the macro `\PrepareIndices` could be changed a bit for that.

The only place where the commands from `xint` are used is in the `\CreateEquations` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{xinttools} % http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xint


% cf etex manual top of page 9
% \PrepareIndices {1}{10} returns {1}....{10}
% \PrepareIndices {i}(j} is empty if i>j
% This code is prepared only for explicit integers
\newcommand\PrepareIndices[2]{%
\ifnum #1<#2
    \expandafter\PrepareIndices
    \expandafter{\number\numexpr#1\expandafter}%
    \expandafter{\number\numexpr#2-1\expandafter}%
    \expandafter{\number\numexpr#2\expandafter}%
\else
  \ifnum #1=#2
    \expandafter{\number\numexpr #1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
  \fi
\fi  }


\newcommand\DoOneEquation[1]{%
     y_{#1} &=A_{#1,\the\numexpr 2*#1-1\relax}
                         x_{\the\numexpr 2*#1-1\relax}
                        +A_{#1,\the\numexpr 2*#1\relax}
                         x_{\the\numexpr 2*#1\relax}%
}


% The next thing uses macros from the xint package, 1.06a or later
% Except from the encapsulation in the align environment, this
% does only completely expandable things
% However, contrarily to my other answers, here when there is
% no equation to typeset because #1>#2, there is still an empty
% align environment created
\newcommand\CreateEquations[2]%
    {\begin{align}
     \xintListWithSep
          {\\}
          {\xintApply{\DoOneEquation}{\PrepareIndices {#1}{#2}}}
     \end{align}}


\begin{document}
  \CreateEquations {1}{5}

  \CreateEquations {1}{-1}

  \CreateEquations {100}{103}

  \CreateEquations{-5}{-5}
\end{document}
```

[image: equations]